# Xcode 12.3 Mac Catalyst code signing fails (code object is not signed at all)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

When I try to submit my app to AppStore for **Mac Catalyst** I get code signing error below. I have no idea how to solve the problem, I have googled everything I found and couldn't find a solution.

Submitting **iOS** version works without any problems.

(Xcode 12.3 & Big Sur 11.1.)

Any ideas?

```
Archives/2020-12-16/Textures 16-12-2020, 14.06.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Textures.app/Contents/Frameworks/BBMetalImage.framework/Versions/A/BBMetalImage'>', hardenedRuntime='0'>'> to: /var/folders/r5/t3j64v0j6td4g8018lfnk0gw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~FGW2X1/entitlements~~~so4QjB
2020-12-16 13:22:05 +0000  Running /usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' '4B7469E3C743F234A6E463B68C9AC62674F2EFD8' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/r5/t3j64v0j6td4g8018lfnk0gw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~FGW2X1/entitlements~~~so4QjB' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/r5/t3j64v0j6td4g8018lfnk0gw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~FGW2X1/Root/Applications/Textures.app/Contents/Frameworks/BBMetalImage.framework/Versions/A'
2020-12-16 13:22:05 +0000  /var/folders/r5/t3j64v0j6td4g8018lfnk0gw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~FGW2X1/Root/Applications/Textures.app/Contents/Frameworks/BBMetalImage.framework/Versions/A: replacing existing signature
2020-12-16 13:22:05 +0000  /var/folders/r5/t3j64v0j6td4g8018lfnk0gw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~FGW2X1/Root/Applications/Textures.app/Contents/Frameworks/BBMetalImage.framework/Versions/A: code object is not signed at all
2020-12-16 13:22:05 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

Comment: In your target’s Frameworks and Libraries settings, what do you have selected for BBMetalImage’s Embed option? Unless you’re not including BBMetalImage that way.

Comment: All third-party libraries I have installed via CocoaPods. What/where could I check what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t use CocoaPods so I don’t know how you check their configuration. But those errors look like the framework is being embedded and/or signed when it shouldn’t be, or isn’t being signed correctly. But like I said, I don’t know how CocoaPods handles that.

Comment: Creating new provisional profile in developer account and install in your keychain. That worked for me.

Comment: Will try it today, thx for info!

Comment: Install in keychain? Provisioning profile cannot be installed into keychain?

Comment: @sabiland curious if/how you solved this?

Comment: Nope, I still have this issue.

Comment: Darn, I'm seeing the same thing, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Stripping the bitcode from the catalyst slices of the framework fixed the error.

So in this case:

`xcrun bitcode_strip -r BBMetalImage -o BBMetalImage`

inside the ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst directory of the .xcframework that the project includes.

This q/a on the same topic helped: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666269

Comment: I had to do this under MyFramworkName. That is MyFramworkName.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/MyFramworkName.framework -> here xcrun bitcode_strip -r MyFramworkName -o MyFramworkName it works ... but then when I try to build the app I have "bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)" ... it looks like it's really a mess including your own framework in mac catalyst